# strange behavior using unset session in if else in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

My current work audit is using CodeIgniter. To improve the traffic and user friendly grade, i have to update some controllers. Now, i have an action, which redirects to the `/index` if there are no records found in the database.

in `/action`

```
} else if ($status == QuestionModel::DATA_EMPTY) {
    $_SESSION['temp'] = 'PROBLEM_DATA_EMPTY';
    $this->index();
}
```

And in `/index` , i check if the page got redirected

```
if(isset($_SESSION['temp']) && ($_SESSION['temp'] == 'PROBLEM_DATA_EMPTY')) {
    $indexModel->setEmptyData();
    unset($_SESSION['temp']);
}
```

The controller doesn't support session addition, so i have to use $_SESSION. *le sigh*

As effect of this, the view page adds an box above the form which says that the data cannot be found and that the user has to use other parameters. It should work without fuzz.
The user would be informed that there is no data at the specified parameters.

But, it doesn't. Moreover, it leads to a strange behavior, that the box won't be displayed, the `setEmptyData()` method isn't being called. I have added `echo 'empty record flag set true'` in the said method to follow it.

Assume that i do the next ;

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
if(isset($_SESSION['temp']) && ($_SESSION['temp'] == 'PROBLEM_DATA_EMPTY')) {
    $indexModel->setEmptyData();
}
```

As you see, i don't remove the `temp` key using `unset()`. It works, the box is displayed, but the session variable stays in the session array, which leads that the message box will be displayed at page refresh. if i check the session by the next ;

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
if(isset($_SESSION['temp']) && ($_SESSION['temp'] == 'PROBLEM_DATA_EMPTY')) {
    $indexModel->setEmptyData();
    unset($_SESSION['temp']);
}
```

the `temp` field is **NOT** available in the session AFTER redirect. The `unset()` thing does the work BEFORE i do the if-check. Heck, the `var_dump()` doesn't display the `temp` key anymore.

In my other try, there is NO unset calls, but an update. The field will be updated with `null`;

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
if(isset($_SESSION['temp']) && ($_SESSION['temp'] == 'PROBLEM_DATA_EMPTY')) {
    $indexModel->setEmptyData();
    $_SESSION['temp'] = null;
}
```

it doesn't work either. The dump shows that the `temp` field is set as null. But the flag won't be toggled, the `setEmptyData()` doesn't occur because `$_SESSION['temp'] == 'PROBLEM_DATA_EMPTY'` is false.

I'm really scratching my head for this behavior at this moment. Does anyone know why this occurs ?

Comment: Why not use the designated [Session library](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) for this?

Comment: good question. I tried it before, but the controller cannot find `$this->session`, which is the reason why i'm using `$_SESSION`. I have informed the IT dept and they didn't have a clue ... (they have weird session structure for authenticate users)

Comment: Read the documentation. I quote: "Sessions will typically run globally with each page load, so the session class must either be initialized in your controller constructors, or it can be auto-loaded by the system. For the most part the session class will run unattended in the background, so simply initializing the class will cause it to read, create, and update sessions.". Read more other the section "Initializing a Session".

Comment: gotcha check the above documenttion. But that doesn't clarify why the `unset()` or `$_SESSION['temp'] = null;` occurs before the if check ...

Comment: have you tried to `$this->load->library('session');` in your controller constructor?